# How to create a component and place on xml page using a button?

Tags: java, android

Basically, this is the code I have right now...

ViewCard activity

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.team46.stubank.R;

public class DisplayCards extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_cards);
    }

    public void viewCard(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ViewCard.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    public void toggleDetails(View view){
        Switch simpleSwitch = findViewById(R.id.switch1);

        TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        TextView tv1 = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        TextView tv2 = findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        TextView tv3 = findViewById(R.id.textView6);

        if (simpleSwitch.isChecked()){
            tv.setText("card.getCardNumber");
            tv1.setText("user.getName");
            tv2.setText("card.getSortCode");
            tv3.setText("card.getAccountNumber");
            //needs to call getter methods from card and user classes
        }
        else{
            tv.setText("0000-0000-0000-0000");
            tv1.setText("Joe Bloggs");
            tv2.setText("11-11-11");
            tv3.setText("3411-4885-6324-7195");
        }
    }

}
```

xml page:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".card_activities.DisplayCards">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="362dp"
        android:layout_height="172dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:onClick="viewCard"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#6C4095"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        app:cardElevation="15dp"
        app:cardMaxElevation="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:onClick="viewCard">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
                android:text="@string/card_number_default"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
                android:text="@string/name_default"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="59dp"
                android:layout_height="47dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/mastercard_small" />

            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/switch1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
                android:onClick="toggleDetails"
                android:text="@string/toggle_card_details"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
                android:text="@string/sortcode_default"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
                android:text="@string/account_number_default"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="79dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#6d0095"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cards_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
            android:text="@string/cards_menu"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="36sp" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The code here is basically a screen with a card, made up of various components, in order to resemble a credit/debit card containing the user's information. Similar to [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=barclays+banking+application+card&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB874GB874&sxsrf=ALeKk035z_mgKdOpDFmVnv-fyDnmzWGckg:1610906215100&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjmoN6lxaPuAhWpVRUIHST9BUMQ_AUoAXoECBYQAw&biw=1366&bih=695#imgrc=V0-VDTvAfYWFBM). What I want to do, is to allow the user to add multiple "cards" by clicking onto a button. I'm not sure how to go about this exactly so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: you have to use recyclerview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 (I think) basic ways to do it - they all involve pulling your single card layout into its own XML file:

- Use the layout as a list item in a `ListView`, or (preferably) a `ViewHolder` in a `RecyclerView`. Each item gets a card layout, and you set the details on the things - the actual data for each card is stored in a list and you just display the appropriate stuff
- Create a custom `View` ([compound controls](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components#compound) really, just bundling some `Views` together) which inherits from something like `FrameLayout`, and inflate your XML layout into that. That way each card is its own object and you can use them as widgets in any other layout
- Make each card a `Fragment` which is a little simpler than creating a `View` (since it handles all the layout inflation stuff for you) but is probably a bit harder to work with in terms of adding them to a layout.

Really it depends what you want - a simple list with a `RecyclerView` might be best, if you want flexibility you could make the custom `View` and stick one of those in a basic layout and use **that** as your `ViewHolder` layout

Comment: thanks, bro I'll go with the recycler view method and see how it goes